# Rules for Lithium batteries in large quantities?

Tags: air-travel, aircraft, batteries

Am I permitted to travel with 50x to 100x lithium batteries, of 45 grams each, which are packed individually in a lithium carry case inside cargo luggage?

It would be cool to know for domestic and international flights.

It is to certify an innovative battery box where batteries can be connected into different arrangements and all insulated into individual unconnected cells by way of a non conductive shielding, for flying with.

Comment: Which airline /route?

Comment: For international travel.

Comment: When you say certifying, do you mean "certifying as safe to fly"? Because that is not something a private citizen would be doing, rather a government agency (eg the FAA in the US).

Comment: The FAA page states that you can carry unlimited amounts of most batteries in luggage as long as they have insulated terminals, so I thought that my box would qualify if the batteries are insulated. Other guides have conflicting statements, so I don't know.

Comment: @Traveller It doesn't matter: the relevant regulations are IATAs and all airlines should implement them.

Comment: I undid your edit because it changed it to a completely different question and invalidated the answer which you have already accepted. If you want to ask a new question, please ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regulations for lithium batteries on flights are made by IATA and they have an [information page](https://www.iata.org/whatwedo/cargo/dgr/Pages/lithium-batteries.aspx). Although we generally discourage link-only answers, I'm not going to attempt to summarize here, since your question requires a high level of technical detail that probably isn't appropriate to this site.

If you're trying to get your product certified, you need to be talking to experts, not to well-meaning folks on the internet. However, in general, lithium-ion cells may not be carried as cargo on passenger flights except if they are installed in a device. I would be very surprised if you could get around that by saying "This special shipping box is a device." It's a shipping box, and that's not allowed.